# Linux Terminal I/O via SPI Device

Tags: console

Is it possible to create a console using the SPI device (/dev/spidev0.0) in a similar way that you would create a serial console, or if not is this possible ??

```
GRUB_TERMINAL=serial 
GRUB_SERIAL_COMMAND="serial --speed=38400 --unit=0 --word=8 --parity=no --stop=1" 
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="console=tty0 console=ttyS0,38400n8 ipv6.disable=1"
```

Or would it be possible to redirect input and output to a script or .c binary and have that handle the SPI ?